# JavaScript - Changing the src of an image with DDL

Tags: javascript, image, src

looked around for this for a while and can't find anything that seems to suit what I need. I want to be able to change the image of a t-shirt to one of a different colour, depending which colour is selected in the drop down menu.

Here's the DDL:

```
<select name="Colours" onchange = "changeImage()">
                    <option value="White">White</option>
                    <option value="Red">Red</option>
                    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
            </select>
```

Here's the JS function I've written (switch statement is repeated for each of the options):

```
           <script type="text/javascript">
               function changeImage(){
                       var x = document.getElementById("Colours").value;
                       switch(x){
                       case "White":
                                  document.Mainimg.src = images/white.jpg;
                                  location.reload();
                                  break;
                       case "Red":
                                 document.Mainimg.src = images/red.jpg;
                                 location.reload();
                                 break;
```

And finally, if it's needed, the code for the image:

```
                <div id="main_img">
                    <img id="Mainimg" name="Mainpic" src=images/white.jpg>
                </div>
```

This doesn't work, nothing happens when I select a new option in the list. Do I have the complete wrong idea of how to do this or is it just a simple tweak?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is this DDL you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `location.reload()` : When you reload the page you lose your changes. The fact you change the `src` of the image is enough to have it loaded.

Use getElementById to fetch your image and put the URL between quotes :

```
document.getElementById('Mainimg').src = "images/white.jpg";
```

The missing quotes could have been discovered simply by using the console which shows compilation errors. Use [the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console).

Comment: If looking a the console doesn't solve the problem, please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so that we can look at it.

Comment: Console tells me I have an unexpected '(' on line 29: document.('Mainimg').src = "images/white.jpg";. Also says that function changeImage is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want to do is this:  http://jsfiddle.net/jWbUv/

HTML:

```
<select name="Colours" onchange = "changeImage(this)">
                    <option value="">please select</option>
                    <option value="White">White</option>
                    <option value="Red">Red</option>
                    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="Purple">Purple</option>
            </select>
 <div id="main_img">
 </div>
```

JS:

```
function changeImage(src) {
    var mainImg = document.getElementById('main_img');
    mainImg.style.setProperty('background-image', 'url(\''+ src.value +'.png\')');
}
```

CSS:

```
 #main_img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: This works great, but how do I replace the URL's with a filepath? My images are in the folder 'images' along with each color: 'white' 'red' etc. Thanks.

Comment: just change the css. You could also achieve the same by doing document.getElementById('main_img').style.backgroundImage = 'url("image-location.png")'; in the javascript function

Comment: #main_img.White{
background-image: url(/images/white.jpg);

I have that, but no image shows. What is it I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Also tried it with '' and "" surround the path with no results.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment until now. I have update the fiddle to this http://jsfiddle.net/jWbUv/2/ . It should work now. Take into consideration that this solution assumes you have a White.png, Yellow.png, Purple.png image. If the image is in another location you can just update it